# Why I get incorrect output of d.toLocaleDateString()?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Why when I try to do so:

```
var d = new Date(2016, 10, 20)
d.toLocaleDateString()
```

I get in output:

```
"11/20/2016"
```

Instead of:

```
"10/20/2016" // as in new Date(2016, 10, 20)
```

Why I get next month in output?

Comment: Month is based on `0`..... `0` - for `jan`, `1` - `feb`,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `month` argument value starts from `0` so it's expected behaviour.

From [MDN docs - description of `month` argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)  :

> Integer value representing the month, ***beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December***.

Comment: Dates in JavaScript is a ... Thanks